# how can I get indexes of multiple selected rows in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a table where user can select multiple rows, however I need to know indexes of top and last selected row, I tried playing with http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QModelIndex.html so far I have this:

```
QItemSelectionModel *selections = this->ui->tableWidget->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList selected = selections->selectedRows(3);
```

But I have no idea how can I use `QItemSelectionModel` to reach the item of table. How can I do that? There is no function in TableWidget that returns item based on `QModelIndex`, only `QPoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the first and last item in the selection range you can simply sort that list. For example:

```
QItemSelectionModel *selections = this->ui->tableWidget->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList selected = selections->selectedRows(3);
qSort(selected);
QModelIndex first = selected.first();
QModelIndex last = selected.last();
```

And now let's get the first and last table items:

```
QTableWidgetItem *firstItem = this->ui->tableWidget->item(first.row(), first.column());
QTableWidgetItem *lastItem = this->ui->tableWidget->item(last.row(), last.column());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `QTableWidget::item(int row, int column)` together with `QModelIndex::column ()` and `QModelIndex::row ()`, respectively, of any help?

Comment: No, it's not, because I have no idea how can I get `QModelIndex` for first and last item in that array of selected rows

Comment: QModelIndexList is a typedef for QList<QModelIndex> where QList has functions like first, last etc.